# Rendering data with API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a question about fetching API in React.js.

CardExample1, CardExample2 and CardExample3 should be only showed 1 of each component.
But there are 5 times of CardExample1 and 5 times of CardExample 2 and so is CardExample3.

I think I should do something in .map method.
How can I make it 1 each of Cards? So only 3 items are on the server
not 15 items(5 items * 3 cards).

I'd like to make it on the server:

CardExample1

CardExample2

CardExample3

However, I can see it now:
CardExample1
CardExample1
CardExample1
CardExample1
CardExample1

CardExample2
CardExample2
CardExample2
CardExample2
CardExample2

CardExample3
CardExample3
CardExample3
CardExample3
CardExample3

JSON data is from ID 1 to ID 5:

```
[
{"id":1,"type":"group","description":"group"},
{"id":2,"type":"shop","description":"shop"}
...
]
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  CardExample1,
  CardExample2,
  CardExample3,
} from './CardExamples.stories';

function examplesPage() {
  const [examples, setExamples] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getExamples = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('/api/examples');
      const examplesResult = await resp.json();
      setExamples(examplesResult );
    };
    getExamples ();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        {examples.map((example) => {
          <CardExample1 key={example.id} example={example} />;
        })}
        {examples.map((example) => {
          <CardExample2 key={example.id} example={example} />;
        })}
        {examples.map((example) => {
          <CardExample3 key={example.id} example={example} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default examplesPage;
```

Comment: Does it matter what `examples` element is used? Can the first example be used as data for all the cards? Or must all the cards use a different element? If so does it matter what element?

Comment: @3limin4t0r all the cards must use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, you can make one `card_example` and map over it one time to make it appear 5 times instead of maping 3 times which in the end will result 3 cards 5 times.

You can do something like this :

```
exemples.map((example_card, i)=> {
<Card_Example />
})
```

If the cards are different (HTML speaking), you can add an algorithm that will filter for you what card to render :

```
function your_algorithm(condition){
 if(example_card.id !== "yourcondition") {
  return (
   <Card_Example_with_condition />
  )
 }
else {
 return (<Card_Example />)
}
}
```

Then in your react render function or return in which you use your HTML display :

```
exemples.map((example_card, i)=> {

 // Call function here along with html
<div>yourfunction()</div>
})
```

Comment: However it's NOT recomended to use it like this, you should have seperated components or HOC (higher order component)

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the components together with the data. Then map over the result.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CardExample1, CardExample2, CardExample3 } from './CardExamples.stories';

function zip(a, b) {
  return a.map((_, i) => [a[i], b[i]]);
}

const CARD_COMPONENTS = [CardExample1, CardExample2, CardExample3];
function examplesPage() {
  const [examples, setExamples] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getExamples = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('/api/examples');
      const examplesResult = await resp.json();
      setExamples(examplesResult);
    };
    getExamples();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {zip(CARD_COMPONENTS, examples)
       .filter(([_, example]) => example)
       .map(([CardExample, example]) => (
         <CardExample key={example.id} example={example} />
       ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default examplesPage;
```